# Does turning off your screen while playing Pokemon Go with mobile data on take up ANY mobile data whatsoever?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a 250mb plan and would like to save as much data as possible. I have the samsung a32 5g.

I sometimes use it while on public transit and would like to know if turning off the screen while the app is running in the foreground will not use any data whatsoever since I don't get a vibration for nearby Pokemon.

Does anyone know if the battery saver screen also saves data or just power?

Comment: If one of the answers below helped you, consider upvoting and accepting by clicking the green "tick"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that keeping the app opened with the screen turned off still uses some data, for example your GPS position is always tracked for egg-hatching, and you can still receive notifications for raid invitations, defeated gyms or whatever.

---

Since you have only a 250MB plan I did some research:

According to [Business insider](https://bgr.com/tech/pokemon-go-data-usage/), on average Pokémon Go eats up about 25MB in an eight-hour period. This works out at about **3MB per hour**.

This [Reddit user](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/87dvey/question_how_much_data_does_pokemon_go_take_up/) says over **7MB per hour** for a very active level 40 player.

Another [Reddit user](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/hwbw7h/ridiculous_data_usage/) plays PoGo for at least 4-6 hours a day and their total for the last month on both data and wifi for Pokemon Go is less than 600MB. (This makes **4MB per hour**, more or less.)

Morever, reloading PoGo seems to use a lot of data, since it has to redownload the local game data - spawns, gyms, map, etc...

It really depends on how much you play on daily basis, so I don't think that your first problem is data spent with turned off screen.

Comment: Thank you, the app tends to crash a lot so maybe I'm using a significant amount just to open it multiple times. I appreciate the info.

Comment: @ShangWang that's unfortunate, have you tried using a different smartphone?

Comment: Nope I only have one phone I never owned one until now I just got it a few months ago lol

Comment: One more thing, do you know if pvp battles will take significantly more data than usual? I have yet to try it.

Comment: @ShangWang I didn't manage to find a source, but I'll go for "yes". PvP and raids need to send and receive data constantly, also because moves and HPs needs to be synched between all players.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks again!

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include this in my question, but that would include raids and such, anything with players in it correct?

What about just Pve battles against rocket grunts?

Comment: @ShangWang Rocket grunts battles are offline, you only need mobile data when catching the shadow Pokemon.

Comment: Thanks again! I noticed that when I was about to leave a building with wifi, went back to catch that poochyena

Comment: Data download usage for Pokemon Go can be decreased by downloading offline Google Maps in the area(s) that you play Pokemon Go beforehand (which can be done over Wifi). The degree of decrease, however, I am unsure of.

Comment: @MBorg is this still true? I know that Pokemon Go used Google Maps data, then switched to OpenStreetMap

Comment: I knew they used Google Maps years ago, but I simply assumed they had continued to do so and wasn't aware that they switched to OpenStreetMap. In that case, my comment may be outdated for PoGo

Comment: Hello, I just wanted to confirm something on Android 11:

If the app is open but the screen is turned off I know data and battery usage will be significantly reduced, but during this time will any battery and data used be only considered "background usage?"

It's impossible for an app to use "foreground data and battery" if the screen is turned off?

Answer (score 3):

> Does turning off your screen while mobile data is on and the game on take up ANY mobile data whatsoever?

Yes.

> Does anyone know if the battery saver screen also saves data or just power?

The battery saver mode simply dims the phone's screen, but keeps everything running in the background. As such, data usage will remain the same.

Comment: Thank you, when you mean "yes" you mean even if I turn off my screen it will still take up some amount of data? Just not a lot right?

Comment: That's correct. Screen off will significantly reduce data usage, but some will still occur.

Comment: Thank you sir! :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, when you mean "some will still occur" do you mean for the phone in general including notifications from other apps, or pokemon go running in the foreground?

Do you know about how much data would be used if I turned my screen off with pokemon go and left it for 4 hours?

Comment: I mean that Pokemon Go will use some amount of mobile data if the app is running regardless of whether this is in the background/foreground, and regardless of if the screen is on or off. I do not know exactly how much data you would expect it to use, and that value almost certainly varies significantly between users.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you! I don't think it would be a big issue if I just turned off my screen to save data than turning off data itself. Sometimes when I do this pokestops and gyms don't show up.

Comment: Hello, sorry to bother you again but do you know what exactly background data usage does for pokemon go? Does it mainly just pertain to notifications? From what I know turning off your screen does not actually notify you of pokemon nearby and doesn't track where you are until you open the app again. What about "allow background activity?" is that essential for adventure sync or anything else?